# Funky Line feeds in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

When I inserted text from one SQL Server VARCHAR(MAX) field in one database to another, I get question mark symbols - "?" - in the target database (in addition to line feeds) whenever there are line feeds in the source database.

Text in the target database looks like this:

Line one.?
?
Line two.?
?

Any ideas about what could cause this, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Do both databases have the same collation? Perhaps they use different encoding and when you pasted it gave you such weird results?

Answer (score 1):

How are you inserting the data and how are you reading the data?

If you do have different collations you can cast on the way in (or out) as required.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179886.aspx

Also you might want to check the quality and source of the data going in. It may need to be cleaned of special characters.